# What is the use scenario of switch_dev_register

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to understand the fsa9485 driver(USB switch). there in dock initialization code I came across:

```
switch_dev_register(&switch_dock)
```

`switch_dock` is a structure of type `switch_dev` and in accessory detection routine it is used like:

```
switch_set_state(&switch_dock, attached)
```

I am inferring like : There are 2 types of dock one being car dock and other being desk dock and `switch_dev` class is for switching between them.

Why do we require `switch_dev` classes??. How that class differentiates between two different dock?

Answer (score 3):

The `switch_dev_register` function registers a device with `sysfs` and creates files in `/sys/`. `Switch_set_state` updates the value in one of the created files on your running kernel (the `state` file). So in my kernel I can see the state by reading a file "/sys/devices/virtual/switch/dock/state." `State` is 1 for `deskdock`, 2 for `cardock`, and 0 otherwise. This is just a simple way of passing hardware information up to userspace.

It is necessary to use the `switch_dev` class for standardization in `sysfs`. The driver differentiates between the two docks by reading register values from the fsa9485 chip which resides on the I2C bus. See `fsa9480_detect_dev` in fsa9480.c where the driver reads values from an analog to digital converter `(ADC)` and a device type register to determine the type of dock.

Comment: okay. I could see that. It is reading ID from the dev type reg. I have  a doubt , is it like only for exporting the device state to sysfs `switch feature(switch_dev_register and switch_set_state)` is used..? it has nothing to do with driver.?

Comment: The driver is doing many things with the information from the ADC and device type registers besides reporting them to sysfs. But the original question was asking about the functionality of switch_dev_register and switch_set_state. But the device type and ADC registers also trigger code that puts the device into USB, OTG, cardock or deskdock mode. For example, in car/desk dock mode, the USB data pins are "switched" to audio outputs and the ID pin is used for control functions such as volume up/down. Look up the specification sheet for the fsa9485 to see the different modes that it supports

Comment: okay from the data sheet specification. For eg: if we consider D+ signal path. It switches between DP_HOST or AUDIO_R or RxD pins depending upon the ID(detection of type of device). Am I clear with understanding and suppose there is similar scenario of switching signaling between 2 or 3 modules(audio/UART/USB) depending upon ID It is mandatory to use `switch_dev_register`..? With this I will be much clear and i would come to one conclusion.

Comment: As you have said: "That is in place to allow a user to manually switch via sysfs instead of the default automatic switching done by the fsa9480 (or fsa9485) chip"                                                     I could see the set_manual_sw routine setting the mode in control reg. So is it like `switch_dev_register` is used in the case when user wants to switch the mode(to manual) via sysfs entry(the client is capable of)..?